# Existe alguma vantagem em evitar redundância de especificação de tipos?

Tags: c#

Dado o seguinte código:

```
public override Entidades.ControleAcesso.Perfil PreencherEntidade(IDataReader dr)
        {
             return  new Entidades.ControleAcesso.Perfil()
                        {
                            Codigo = FieldSafer.Safe<int>(dr["someCol"], 0),
                            Nome = FieldSafer.Safe<string>(dr["someCol"], "nothing"),
                            PerfilFuncionalidade = new List<PerfilFuncionalidade>(),
                            StatusRegistro = FieldSafer.Safe<StatusRegistroEnum>(dr["someCol"], StatusRegistroEnum.Ativo),
                        };
        }
```

Onde FieldSafer =

```
public class FieldSafer : MinhaClasseBase
    {
        private T ObjectSafe<T>(object field, T defaultValue)
        {
            return GetSafeField<T>(field, defaultValue);
        }

        public static T Safe<T>(object field, T defaultValue)
        {
            return new FieldSafer().ObjectSafe<T>(field, defaultValue);
        }
    }
```

sofro no caso de uma redundância aqui:   `Codigo = FieldSafer.Safe<int>(dr["someCol"], 0),`
onde deixo explicito o meu `Safe<int>`, onde poderia ser automaticamente suprimido por `Safe(dr...` sendo que o retorno (`defaulValue`) é um inteiro.

é Correto suprimir redundância de tipos? ou para facilitar o entendimento é melhor deixa-los explícitos?

Comment: esses metodos fazem o que? pega um DataReader e tranformar em um Tipo de classe ? se puder responder ?

Comment: Desculpe a demora, Sim, esses métodos recebem o retorno do Banco de Dados e transformam em um objeto

Comment: Eu tenho uma rotina que tranformar dados que vem do Banco lidos por um datareader é uma lista, se quiser trazer um item também funciona ... se você achar legal te passo como resposta! @okevinlira

Comment: Poste como Reposta @FCCDias é bom ter outra opiniao para avaliar também. Particularmente existem outras maneiras de se fazer isso, mas nao posso alterar essa estrutura a pedido de meu cliente ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nos casos apresentados, como o valor sendo passado é um literal, é muito fácil perceber qual tipo será inferido pelo C#... então nesse caso, eu com certeza removeria a especificação do tipo da chamada genérica.

Em outros casos em que há maior complexidade do valor sendo passado, dependendo da situação, talvez seja melhor deixar os tipos explícitos.

Particularmente, eu nunca deixo os tipos especificados quando eles podem ser inferidos pelo compilador, pois o Visual Studio permite saber qual é o tipo, simplesmente passando o mouse sobre o método.

Em termos de performance, não existe diferença, pois quando o compilador infere o tipo, é como se você tivesse especificado o tipo... o resultado compilado será o mesmo. Ou seja, a diferença é apenas visual.

Comment: Cara.. se tu soubesse como vc foi ninja agora, editando exatamente o que eu iria perguntar :P

Comment: Hehe... esqueci de responder a parte principal da pergunta: o título! Mas agora acho que tá tudo certo e coerente. =)